# how to point connect-session-sequelize session store to required database schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, express-session

In my Node.js application using `express-session` for session management and [connect-session-sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-session-sequelize) for storing session (persistent storage - Postgres) .

I have created a schema (e.g: myschema) in my database which exists apart from the default `public` and I want to point my session storage to myschema.
By default `connect-session-sequelize` library is pointing to `public` schema and cannot find an option/parameter to change database schema.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried the `table` parameter - reflecting your `"other_schema"."table_name" as a Sequelize Model?`

Comment: Yes @madflow, I have tried. But, not working.

Comment: The library is rather small. Maybe you could just create a PR with the database schema as an optional config parameter? Or hack around it: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted the same issue in the [github library](https://github.com/mweibel/connect-session-sequelize/issues/113). The owner has closed the issue mentioning that schema configuration must be set at database object.

But, I do not think that is correct because

1. if db object is specific to particular schema it will be difficult to access other schemas in the same database.
2. Also, it is breach of design principles to create db object for each db schema.
3. Moreover, `Sequelize` does not allow to configure schema.

This is an issue in `connect-session-sequelize`, so make sure you do not have such requirement (pointing to custom schema) while using this library.